# How do I open one Excel file from another without including the current user in the pathname?

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula, pathname

I am working on multiple Excel files with colleagues, using Dropbox to collaborate.

We all have Dropbox integrated with Finder on our Macs.

I want to be able to open one file by clicking on a link in another file - I've tried using the hyperlink function but I can't figure out the pathname without including the user's name.

i.e. anyone who has the same Dropbox file directory should be able to open the other spreadsheet, whether it be through a relative path or an absolute path from their root directory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using a button to do this in one of my workbooks.  Not sure if it is the same for you but I have the directory in cell A1 (or you could just put the directory in there).  This is used as a macro set to a button.

```
Sub OpenWorkbook_Click()

Dim Book1 As Workbook
Dim wbName As String
On Error Resume Next
Set MPL = Workbooks.Open(Sheet4.Range("A1").Value)
wbName = Book1.Name

End Sub
```